# Recommended style for using indices in nested for loops in python

Tags: python

Consider a C style nested for loop like so:

```
for i = 0; i < n; i++ {
    for j = i; j < n; j++ {
        do_something();
    }
}
```

What is the recommended python translation for that?

Following [Effective Python](http://www.effectivepython.com), which dictates that `range(len(something))` should be avoided and `enumerate` should be used wherever possible, I'm thinking of:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(some_iter):
    for j in range(i, len(some_iter)):
        do_something()
```

but mix of `enumerate` and `range` appears inconsistent.

Whereas,

```
for i in range(len(some_iter)):
    for j in range(i, len(some_iter)):
        do_something()
```

looks consistent but uses `range(len(some_iter))`.

What is the recommended Python style for this?

Comment: just use `range`, you aren't using the actual value of the iterable in enumerate, or at least, that is what you imply with `for i, _ in enumerate(some_iter)`, in which case you should *prefer `range`*.

Comment: IOW: "enumerate should be used wherever possible" is not true. It should be used when you want to *enumerate* something, whether that be to give you an index along with the value, or just for counting iterations while you get your value, e.g. `page_no, val in enumerate(pages, 1)`

Comment: If you're looking for a pattern to follow whenever possible, tend towards `for i in lst:`.  Something like `for i in range(len(lst)): for j in lst[i:]: do something(j)` may suit your needs

Comment: I completely agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga here. `enumerate` should not _always_ strived to be used, especially at the cost of readability and clarity. There are perfect valid use cases for `range(len(...)`. `enumerate` is only meant to replace the common pattern of need an element and index while iterating over an iterable.

Comment: I haven't read the book, but I'm guessing that "*range(len(something)) should be avoided and enumerate should be used wherever possible*" is there to stop people writing C-in-Python by writing `for i in range(len(some_iter)): item = some_iter[i]` instead of `for i, item in enumerate(some_iter):` but range and enumerate are different and if you need a range but not an item, there's no need for enumerate.

Comment: Definitely `for i, _ in enumerate(some_iter):` is not the way to do anything.

Comment: While it's true that `enumerate` that doesn't use the produced item is strange, just about any time you are using `range(len(someseq))` you're probably doing it wrong; the only serious exception is if you need to iterate over slices of a sequence (so the individual item is useless, and you need a slice from `i` to `i+k` where `k` is the slice size). The OP's question is impossible to answer because they haven't shown what purpose the loop serves; if `i` is being used for indexing something, it's probably better to substitute `enumerate` or `zip`, but we don't have the information to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, you're not actually using `i` or `j` for anything, so the nested loop is nonsense; you could just loop a calculated number of times as a single top-level loop.

That said, it follows the pattern commonly seen for processing all unique pairings from a given input sequence, and that [is a solved problem in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
import itertools

for x, y in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(some_iter, 2):
    do_something(x, y)
```

is the Pythonic equivalent, without unnecessary indexing, of:

```
for i in range(len(some_iter)):
    for j in range(i, len(some_iter)):
        do_something(some_iter[i], some_iter[j])
```

If you also needed the index, just pair it with `enumerate`:

```
for (ix, x), (iy, y) in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(enumerate(some_iter), 2):
    do_something(ix, x, iy, y)
```

Using `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` (with or without `enumerate`) is going to be more efficient, and more general: If you're relying on indexing, you limit your inputs to *sequences*, so arbitrary iterables (`set`, `dict`, generator expressions, etc.) won't work without converting them to a sequence first. Using the Pythonic approach means you can accept and work with any finite iterable without needing to perform manual type conversions and indexing.

Comment: Side-note: As a rule, most of the time when people think they need `range(len(someseq))`, and half the time they think they need `enumerate`, claiming it's because their use case is too complicated, they really just don't know the `zip` function and the `itertools` module very well; between the two of them and list comprehensions, they cover almost everything you'd ever need. In many of those `enumerate` cases, the problem can be solved by a simple list comprehension to generate a new `list`, rather than index assigning to the old one for instance (a common use for `enumerate`).

Answer (score 0):

I try to use for `item in itemList:` whenever I can, instead of using `i` as a variable, and `i` as an iterator.

```
for i in some_iter:
    for j in some_iter[some_iter.index(i):-1]
        doSomething()
```

so the second `for` loop slices the list from the index of the current item to the end.

Comment: Using `index` is adding a wasteful (and inaccurate for non-unique inputs) linear scan before each inner loop; `enumerate`-ing the outer loop would give you the index for free. Also, it's a bad idea to use `i` (or `j`) as a name for anything but an index variable, since programming traditions use it exclusively for that purpose, so it's misleading to use it for the actual value.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I personally don't usually use i and j as names, I was just following the format of the poster. I would normally give it a meaningful name.